# Track read/unread emails only on certain devices

Tags: email, synchronization, imap, pop3

I use a mailbox shared with some colleagues, each one of us use pop3 because each one wants to keep track of which emails has been read by himself. (Each one needs to read all the emails of that mailbox even if someone else has already read it).
Now i would use that mailbox on my different devices (iPhone, Mac, pc, etc) and i would love if should be possible to keep track of the emails read by me throught my different devices.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the same web based (POP3) email reader on all devices then you will achieve your goal.

You cannot do this by staying with different mail clients on all of your devices, changing server side only, because a POP3 server does not track who reads what at all.

AFAIK IMAP stores all information primarily on the server side, so it may be possible what you want even on server side. But then you have to switch to IMAP for everybody or you have to import the mails into a private IMAP server for you.

Comment: What do you mean for "the same web based (POP3) email reader"?

Comment: @gattol: a browser is available on all the devices you have, so you can use a single, browser based mail program, which has the capability to work with a foreign POP account.

Comment: Then you have to use IMAP.